# Cannot pass this because wrong conversion of class type

Tags: c++, c++11, this

I have defined the two following classes in two different files:

```
#include "B.h"
class A {
 public:
  A() {}
  ~A() {}
  f() {
   auto b = new B(this);
  }
};
```

And in another file:

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
 public:
  B(A* a) {}
  ~B() {}
}
```

But I don't understand the compile error I get:

```
B.h: error: ‘A’ has not been declared
A.cpp: error: no matching function for call to ‘B(A&)‘
                                                      *this);
              note: candidate is:
              note: B(int*)
              note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘int*’
```

Why is my A class has been converted to int ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a ciucular dependency issue. `B.h` includes `A.h`, and `A.h` includes `B.h`.

In fact, you don't need the `#include "A.h"` in `B.h`, `A` doesn't need to be [complete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) here (i.e. use it as the parameter type in the function declaration), [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) is sufficient.

```
class A;  // forward declaration

class B {
 public:
  B(A* a) {}
  ~B() {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular dependency here. The definition of `class A` can't depend on the definition of `class B`, if the latter depends on the definition of the former. You can get around this by transforming one of the `#include` directives into a forward declaration. In your case,

```
// Don't include the complete definition
// #include "A.h"

class A; // Instead: forward-declare A

class B {
  public:
   B(A* a) {}
  ~B() {}
};
```

You probably need the definition of `A` in your implementation file nevertheless. But this is fine, you can `#include "A.h"` in a translation unit without falling back to the circular dependency issue.